# Probability with cards without replacement

Tags: probability, card-games

If theres 48 in a deck and 24 of them are red and 24 of them are black. Whats the probability that the next card is red, when 4 out of 12 cards drawn  are red without replacement?

Does the success rate(4/12, 33%) influence what the next card drawn will be ? i.e. 
How would you go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

If the deck is shuffled properly, the chance of any card that is drawn will only be affected by how many of each colour are left in the deck. The fact that that you've drawn four red cards only affects the probability in that there are four fewer red cards in the deck.

If you've drawn 12 cards and four of them are red, then 8 are black. Therefore there are 36 cards left, 20 of which are red and 16 of which are black. So the probability of drawing a red card next is $\frac{20}{36} = \frac{5}{9}$.

Comment: Since 5/9 is equal to  55.55%  that means i have a +5.55% chance of getting a red card. What % margin is big enough to say i will get a  red card?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you asking how to guarantee you get a red card? For that you would need every card in the deck to be red.

Comment: lets say you have a 80 % chance of getting a red card. The probability of getting a black card is really low only 20%. But the chances of getting high probability like 80% is less than likely its more like to fall between 40%-60%. So is it safe to say that  the probability of getting a red card at 55% and higher will  more than likely guarantee me a red card. At a 5% advantage is it less likely the odds will beat it ?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what probability means. You can't say anything about the likelihood of getting a red card beyond what you've calculated for the probability. If there is a 5/9 chance of drawing a red card, then you're certainly more likely to get a red card then a black card, since 5/9 > 50%. But the only point at which you can say that you WILL get a red card is if the probability is 100%.

Comment: What about finding the probability of defying the odds?

Comment: In this case, 'defying the odds' would mean getting the less likely outcome, so drawing a black card. So the probability would be 4/9.

Comment: So P (Black cards) , P (Defying the odds) = P (Black n Defying the odds) = P ( 4/9 × 5/9) = 20/81 or 24.7% So theres a 24.7%  chance of it happening. Would that be considered true.

Comment: No. The thing is, 'defying the odds' isn't really defined mathematically. I assumed you meant getting the less likely option. What exactly are you trying to calculate here?

Comment: Im wondering if the probability is high i.e. 5/9 and the next card drawn is not the red card. It just beat the odds. I wanna know how could i figure out the chances of it happening again. Is there an equation for that.

Comment: If there's a $5/9$ chance that the next card drawn is red, then there is a $1-(5/9) = 4/9$ chance that it is not red. If that happens, then there will now be 15 black cards left in a deck of 35 cards, so if you draw again, the probability that you will get another black card is $\frac{15}{35} = \frac{3}{7}$. So the probability of drawing two black cards in a row would be $\frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{30}{7}$ $= \frac{4}{21}$ $\approx$ 19.0%.